# Required If validation for Laravel array with empty value

Tags: php, laravel, request

I have the following input

```
{
    "password":"password",
    "environment_roles":[
        {
            "environment_id":"",
            "role_id":""
        }
    ],
    "admin":true    
}
```

and have a Request class with following rules :

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'password'                              => 'required|min:6|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/',
            'environment_roles'                     => 'array',
            'environment_roles.*.role_id'           => 'required_if:admin,false|exists:roles,role_id',
            'environment_roles.*.environment_id'    => 'required_if:admin,false|exists:environment,environment_id',
            'admin'                                 => 'sometimes'
        ];
    }
```

But it is showing the following validation error if I give the above input, which has `admin` as `true`.

```
"validation": {
            "environment_roles.0.role_id": [
                "The selected environment_roles.0.role_id is invalid."
            ],
            "environment_roles.0.environment_id": [
                "The selected environment_roles.0.environment_id is invalid."
            ]
        },
```

How can I fix this. I need to validate the `environment_roles.*.role_id` and `environment_roles.*.environment_id` when the value for `admin` is true.

Comment: shows what validation message?

Comment: have you looked into the `exclude_if` and `exclude_unless` rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always sending the admin prop it would be more suitable to make it nullable not required. You could try with that:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'password'                              => 'required|min:6|regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/',
        'environment_roles'                     => 'array',
        'environment_roles.*.role_id'           => 'nullable|required_if:admin,false|exists:roles,role_id',
        'environment_roles.*.environment_id'    => 'nullable|required_if:admin,false|exists:environment,environment_id',
        'admin'                                 => 'bool|sometimes'
    ];
}
```

But your error shows that the role and the environment id's does not exist in the database ( The exists rule ). Setting those two fields to nullable means it will not trigger the exists rule.